# How to modify a class variable through innerclass itemListener?

Tags: java, awt, inner-classes, itemlistener

I have the following code here:

```
public class A extends Runnable {
  ArrayList<String> choosenFiles;

  run(){
  /*graphic stuff such as JFrame,JLabel,JButtons*/
  }

  private ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
  /*options*/
  }

  public class cbListener implements ItemListener {
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        Checkbox cb = (Checkbox)e.getItemSelectable();
        String cbl = cb.getLabel();

        if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "selected:\n" + cbl);
            choosenFiles.add(cbl);
        } else if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "deselected:\n" + cbl);
            choosenFiles.remove(cbl);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem seems to be that `CBListener` can not reach `choosenFile` since an `AWT-EventQueue-0 java.lang.NullPointerException` comes up.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at FileDownloader.Client.User$cbListener.itemStateChanged(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Checkbox.processItemEvent(Checkbox.java:563)
at java.awt.Checkbox.processEvent(Checkbox.java:530)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4660)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4488)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:674)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:81)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:633)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:631)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege
(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege
(AccessControlContext.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:647)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:645)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege
(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:644)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Post the stacktrace. Have you initialized `choosenFiles`?

Comment: Stacktrace posted editing the main post. I did initialize  choosenFile to null

Comment: If it's `null`, then there is no object referenced. You can't call methods on `null`.

Comment: How should I initialize it then? Sorry for the stupid question I'm a newby...

Comment: To an object. Use an instance creation expression, like `new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: I'm so stupid sometimes...it worked! Can't say how much I'm grateful!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `choosenFiles` has not been initialized; this should happen early on, e.g. in the constructor or an initialization method.
Also it is good practice to use the most general interface possible, so if there's not a very good reason for `choosenFiles` do be defined as an `ArrayList<String>`, make it a `List<String>`.

Comment: thanks a lot but it worked using ArrayList anyway I just forget to initialize it as you said...thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome @Irith. About the ArrayList, what I would suggest is changing the definition to `List<String>` and testing that; there are very few cases where the program has to know that it's an `ArrayList` (which is a specialization of `List`). You can do stuff like this: `List<String> choosenFiles = new ArrayList<>()`.

Comment: I change it in List<String> as you suggest and it obviously works so thanks for teaching me new things! I appreciate it a lot!